# Cannoct connect CockroachDB Serverless with Ruby/Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel, cockroachdb

To connect a CockrachDB Serverless, I have to pass some parameters in the connection string (`?sslmode=verify-full&options=--cluster%3Dblackstack-4545`).

The full connection string looks like this:

```
postgresql://blackstack:<db-password>@free-tier14.aws-us-east-1.cockroachlabs.cloud:26257/blackstack?sslmode=verify-full&options=--cluster%3Dblackstack-4545
```

From Ruby, such a connection string works fine if I use the `pg` gem, but it fails if I use `Sequel`.

Here is the testing code:

```rb
require 'pg'
require 'sequel'
    
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://blackstack:<db-password>@free-tier14.aws-us-east-1.cockroachlabs.cloud:26257/blackstack?sslmode=verify-full&options=--cluster%3Dblackstack-4545"
    
conn = PG.connect(DATABASE_URL)
p conn.exec("SELECT 'Hello CockroachDB!' AS message").first
# => {"message"=>"Hello CockroachDB!"}
    
DB = Sequel.connect(DATABASE_URL)
p DB["SELECT 'Hello CockroachDB!' AS message"].first
# => "/home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:637:in `async_connect_or_reset': PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  codeParamsRoutingFailed: missing cluster identifier (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)"
```

Here is the full output of the command:

```bash
leandro@dev5:~/code/mysaas/examples/1.db$ ruby 1.connect.rb
{"message"=>"Hello CockroachDB!"}
/home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:637:in `async_connect_or_reset': PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  codeParamsRoutingFailed: missing cluster identifier (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:707:in `new'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:208:in `connect'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:122:in `make_new'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:209:in `assign_connection'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:139:in `acquire'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:91:in `hold'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:269:in `synchronize'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:278:in `test_connection'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/misc.rb:175:in `initialize'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:57:in `new'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:57:in `connect'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:124:in `connect'
    from 1.connect.rb:10:in `<main>'
/home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:637:in `async_connect_or_reset': FATAL:  codeParamsRoutingFailed: missing cluster identifier (PG::ConnectionBad)
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:707:in `new'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:208:in `connect'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:122:in `make_new'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:209:in `assign_connection'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:139:in `acquire'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:91:in `hold'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:269:in `synchronize'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:278:in `test_connection'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/misc.rb:175:in `initialize'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:57:in `new'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:57:in `connect'
    from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sequel-5.56.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:124:in `connect'
    from 1.connect.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it my self.

I worked with the below connection string using the format cluster_name.db_name instead.

```
postgresql://blackstack:<db-password>@free-tier14.aws-us-east-1.cockroachlabs.cloud:26257/blackstack-4545.blackstack?sslmode=verify-full
```